# What TTL value should i use to make sure the packet never leaves the broadcast domain

Tags: ip, ttl

If i put the TTL as 0, will it never leave my broadcast domain? If I wanna send something to someone in my broadcast domain, can the ttl be 0 or will it still be dropped? Or should it be 1?

Answer (score 2):

Packets with TTL `0` will be dropped at the interface.

Link-local protocols, like multicast (by default), use a TTL of `1` to be confined to the broadcast domain.

Comment: Multicast is not *by default* link-local. Some groups are, but the protocol itself is not. (multicast routing is a thing.)

Comment: Yes multicast routing is a thing, but part of that increases the TTL, which from the sender is normally `1`. That is something that gets people when first trying to route multicast traffic. The multicast router sets the TTL to somethng larger than `1`.

Comment: MR does *not* change (reset) the TTL. The user / application must set the TTL appropriately. A router is supposed to drop link-local group traffic with a TTL != 1. Eg. if you want multicast NTP to span your network, *you* have to set the TTL to something other than 1.

Answer (score 1):

See [RFC 791](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc791):

> If the
> time to live reaches zero before the internet datagram reaches its
> destination, the internet datagram is destroyed.

Accordingly, a packet with TTL=0 can only be processed locally but cannot be sent anywhere any more. TTL=1 guarantees a packet cannot be forwarded outside the local subnet.

Most implementations decrease TTL on reception and drop the packet before it is sent from any interface.